# I can't reach my current instance to change a label

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change a label text from my function class in the main form. I think I was able to narrow down the problem, but I can't find a good solution. Maybe I misunderstood the instances in WinForms.

Favorite solution
Form 1

```
public static Form1 f1Instance;
public Label lbl;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    f1Instance = this;
    lbl = label1;   //label1 = made by designer
}
```

Class 1 (can the problem be that i put my functions in a class and not a winform?)

```
public void changeLblTxt(string txt)
{
    Form1.f1Instance.lbl.Text = txt;
}
```

But that didn't work and I don't understand why. Doesn't that call the currently displayed instance of Form1?

Solution that works
Form 1

```
public static Form1 f1Instance;
public Label lbl;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    f1Instance = this;
    lbl = label1;    //label1 = made by designer
}
```

Class 1

```
public void changeLblTxt(string txt)
{
    Form1.f1Instance.lbl.Text = "Hello";
    Form1.f1Instance.Show();
}
```

But I use it to call Form1 multiple times, don't I? That wouldn't go well with a longer runtime and more interactions, would it?

I have found countless articles on this subject but none have been able to help. Does anyone know of an article that shows a good solution?

Comment: What is that static form for? If you have several `Form1`, `f1Instance` would point to the last one (I guess, it's weird). You should just use the actual instance, nothing should be static. Where is `Form1` being created? Just use that object.

Comment: You need to pass the instance of the form : changeLblTxt(Form1 form1, string txt){form1.f1Instance.lbl.Text = "Hello";}

Comment: @jdweng, `f1Instance` is static, it doesn't belong to any instance, `form1.f1Instance` won't compile.

Comment: Should be :  changeLblTxt(Form1 form1, string txt){form1.lbl.Text = "Hello";}

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class that interacts with the form, then that class should have a reference to the form instance. Using static fields and lists to try and get the "current" form instance seems like a poor design.

I would just hand the class the form instance:

```
class Class1 {
   private Form1 form1;
   public Class1(Form1 form1) {
       this.form1 = form1;
   }
   // other stuff 
}

Form1 frm = new Form1();
Class1 cls1 = new Class1(frm);
cls1.changeLblTxt("Test");
```

And similarly if you have two forms:

```
class Form2: Form {
   private Form1 form1;
   public Form2(Form1 form1) {
       this.form1 = form1;
   }
   // other stuff 
}

Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(frm1);
fmr2.someMethod("Test");
```